# iOS - Parse - PFQuery Not Working

Tags: ios, parse-platform, key-value, pfquery

I am creating a custom class `ChatRequest`, but when I try to query it, it will not return any custom keys.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"ChatRequest"];
    [query setValue:[PFUser currentUser].username forKey:@"toUser"];
    NSArray *objects = [query findObjects];
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < objects.count; i++) {
        PFObject *object = [objects objectAtIndex:i];
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Chat Request!" message:object.sendingUser + @"wants to chat with you!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Decline" otherButtonTitles:@"Accept", nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
}
```

Can anyone help? I checked that my class was correct and the keys were there, but it still won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't use `setValue` to add a constraint to a query.  You use `whereKey:equalTo:`, so your code should be:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"ChatRequest"];
    [query whereKey:@"toUser" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser].username ];
    NSArray *objects = [query findObjects];
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < objects.count; i++) {
        PFObject *object = [objects objectAtIndex:i];
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Chat Request!" message:object.sendingUser + @"wants to chat with you!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Decline" otherButtonTitles:@"Accept", nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
}
```

However, for performance reasons it is a bad idea to call the find objects synchronously like this.  You should use `- (void)findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:(PFArrayResultBlock)block` to allow the query to complete in the background.  In the completion block you can refresh your UI.

Also, from a design point of view your `toUser` should be a reference type column, not a string type.  You could then use

```
[query whereKey:@"toUser" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
```

Comment: it still does not work when I try to access the username property:
`object[@"sendingUser"].username`

Comment: If `sendingUser` is a reference type column then you need to add `[query includeKey:@"sendingUser"]` to have the Parse API retrieve the referenced object

Comment: it gives `property 'username' not found on object of type (id)`

Comment: You need to cast the object - `PFUser *sender=(PFUser *)object[@"sendingUser"]; NSString *senderName=sender.username`